# How set text in textview and formatted it as code? (Android Java)

Tags: java, android

So the question is this. I'm writing the app and I want to show part of "java code" in TextView, so when I set Text in TextView it looks like a simple text.

Is it possible to show the "code" like code with all tag color, etc?

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import br.tiagohm.codeview.Language;
import br.tiagohm.codeview.Theme;
import io.github.kbiakov.codeview.CodeView;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class FragmentActivityTop extends Fragment implements br.tiagohm.codeview.CodeView.OnHighlightListener {
    CodeView mCodeView;
int tag=0;
    public FragmentActivityTop() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        //CodeProcessor.init(getContext());
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment_top, container, false);

        //CodeView codeView = (CodeView) v.findViewById(R.id.code_viewjava);

        String code = "   @Override\n" +
                "    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,\n" +
                "                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {\n" +
                "        // Inflate the layout for this fragment\n" +
                "        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_xml, container, false);\n" +
                "\n" +
                "        WebView webView = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webfragxml);";


        mCodeView = (CodeView)v.findViewById(R.id.codeView);

        mCodeView.setOnHighlightListener(this)
                .setOnHighlightListener(this)
                .setTheme(Theme.AGATE)
                .setCode(code)
                .setLanguage(Language.JAVA)
                .setWrapLine(true)
                .setFontSize(14)
                .setZoomEnabled(true)
                .setShowLineNumber(true)
                .setStartLineNumber(9000)
                .apply();

        return v;
    }


    @Override
    public void onStartCodeHighlight() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinishCodeHighlight() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLanguageDetected(Language language, int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFontSizeChanged(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLineClicked(int i, String s) {

    }
}
```

This is my Fragment code when I trying to do this:
mCodeView.setOnHighlightListener(this)

setOnHightkightListener paint are in red.

```
08-19 18:30:37.308 17929-17929/tj.horun.las.learnandroidstudio D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                                                                             --------- beginning of crash
```

08-19 18:30:37.314 17929-17929/tj.horun.las.learnandroidstudio E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: tj.horun.las.learnandroidstudio, PID: 17929
                                                                                 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class io.github.kbiakov.codeview.CodeView
                                                                                 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class io.github.kbiakov.codeview.CodeView
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.github.kbiakov.codeview.CodeView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/tj.horun.las.learnandroidstudio-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/tj.horun.las.learnandroidstudio-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/tj.horun.las.learnandroidstudio-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/tj.horun.las.learnandroidstudio-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/tj.horun.las.learnandroidstudio-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/tj.horun.las.learnandroidstudio-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/tj.horun.las.learnandroidstudio-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/tj.horun.las.learnandroidstudio-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/tj.horun.las.learnandroidstudio-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/tj.horun.las.learnandroidstudio-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/tj.horun.las.learnandroidstudio-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/tj.horun.las.learnandroidstudio-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/tj.horun.las.learnandroidstudio-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
                                                                                     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:609)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                                     at tj.horun.las.learnandroidstudio.LayoutFragment.onCreateView(LayoutFragment.java:28)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2239)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1332)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1574)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1641)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:794)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2415)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2200)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2153)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2034)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:651)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1239)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1087)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:270)
                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:618)
                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6274)
08-19 18:30:37.315 17929-17929/tj.horun.las.learnandroidstudio E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: Hello Horun, welcome to SO, kindly tell what did you try so far?
The code you posted is not even related to the question....

Comment: Hi, I wrote the code just for example what I want to see on the screen when I set text in textview. Now, I will try to use HTML.fromHtml.

Comment: I used library of Kirill Biakov, it work good but unfortunately, I can't copy text from codeview. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this library](https://github.com/tiagohm/CodeView?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=5097) to enable code highlighting.

Comment: When I use this library I have some issues if I use it in Fragment.

Comment: @HorunDjavariev what issues do you have?

Comment: mCodeView.setOnHighlightListener(this)
      .setOnHighlightListener(this)
      .setTheme(Theme.AGATE)
      .setCode(JAVA_CODE)
      .setLanguage(Language.JAVA)

Comment: "this" didn't work in fragment, I also use context, get context, getactivity no one worked.

Comment: @HorunDjavariev do you make your fragment implements onHilightListener?

Comment: mCodeView.setOnHighlightListener(this)
               
Yes I implement it, now setOnHightligtListener are red and don't work.

Comment: looks on Top, please.

Comment: @HorunDjavariev I've looked. So, u do not use listener, just remove two lines(SetOnHighlight... Is repeating twice, remove both) and remove implements... from fragment

Comment: Didn't help, after removing one setter next setter painted red and next like this too.

Comment: not a red line, red text. It shows that it doesn't know this command at all

Comment: @HorunDjavariev oh, I found problem. U use another library, not I suggest u. U use 'io.github.kbiakov.codeview' but it should be 'com.github.tiagohm:CodeView'. Change build.gradle dependency to match that.

Comment: Yes, I used both of them. As you wrote in build.gradle i deleted the first and leave only tiagohm. It help, now I dont have problem. But here another one problem, now When I open my project in real phone after 4 sec it crash

Comment: I add the Log cat on main post

Comment: @HorunDjavariev u have not changed your layout when you have been changing the library.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed it. Спасибо за помошь

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CodeView](https://github.com/amrdeveloper/codeview) Library and set the configuration for the language that you want then just use setText and it will be highlighted with any color you want and you can change the theme in the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, its possible to do using html.
You can use Html.fromHtml() to set text like java code and color.